# Getting rails application from github to debian server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, debian, passenger

I've been developing my first rails application on my windows computer.
But now i have been setting up a debian server with nginx and passanger.
I've been using Github to keep track of my application and now i am wondering how i can get the Github version of my application to the debian server and put it in production mode?

Anybody that have a good guide about this or something?

Comment: If you don't know how to check things out of git then what have you been using it for all this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the code to your production server is just the tip of the iceberg. What if you want to rollback to the previous version? Or tag a specific version and deploy it? How will you deal with different versions of configuration files for your development vs. production scenarios?

That's why you need [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano). It lets you do all this (and more) from the command line of your development machine. Take a look at the ["From the Beginning"](http://www.capify.org/index.php/From_The_Beginning) chapter to get started.

You'll also need some basic knowledge of shell commands and SSH.

Also have a look at the [Phusion Passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_ror_app) to see what is needed on the server side.